# how to Create Histogram for one variable, using another to determine its frequency?

Tags: r, histogram

I'm new to R, and am using Histograms for the first time.  I need to construct a histogram chart to show the frequency of income for all 50 United States + District of Columbia.

This is the data given to me:

```
> data
  X.Income. X.No.States.
1   -22.024            5
2   -25.027           13
3   -28.030           16
4   -31.033            9
5   -34.036            4
6   -37.039            2
7   -40.042            2
> hist(data$X.Income, col="red")
```

But that only produces a histogram of the number of frequency that each income amount appears in the graph, not the number of states that have that level of income.  How do I account for the number of states that have each level of income in the chart?
[image: Look at my histogram here]

Comment: If you need a weighted histogram, `library(plotrix);with(data, weighted.hist(X.Income, X.No.States))`

Comment: I get an error saying "Error in library(plotrix): There is no package called plotrix"

Comment: `install.packages("plotrix")`

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bar plot instead of a histogram, as the histogram expects to calculate the frequencies for you:

```
library(ggplot2)

# make some data to exercise
income = c(-22.024, -25.027, -28.030, -31.033, -34.036, -37.039,-40.042)
freq = c(5,13,16,9,4,2,2)
df <- data.frame(income, freq)
df <- names(c("income","freq"))

# the graph object
p <- ggplot(data=df) +
   aes(x=income, y=freq) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="red")

# call the object to view
p
```

Comment: Also, you could vary the width of the bars proportionate to `sqrt(population)` of each state/district.